# How to pass form variables to URL

Tags: php

I have a php page which is set to update an SQL record. This part works okay. The code has been written to redirect to page

`watch_process.php?username='".$_POST['Username']."'`

Which works fine and i can see the url has been amended correctly on the watch_process.php page when it loads. However, when I try to call it and print it on my php webpage, I get nothing.

```
<?php echo $_GET['username'] ?>
```

url looks like this: http://netfox-social.co.uk/watch_process.php?username=%27sysadmin%27&

Comment: use `trim($_POST['Username'])` in the url. Or use `urlencode($_POST['Username'])`

Comment: You could try `$_REQUEST['username']`. Request works for both, get and post. And I think the some of the quotes on the row `watch_process.php?username='".$_POST['Username']."'` are unneccessary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try `$_REQUEST['username']` Request works for both, get and post. And I think the some of the quotes on the row `watch_process.php?username='".$_POST['Username']."'` are unneccessary

Answer by AirPett (See comments)

Answer (score 1):

Have you any special intention in doing this?

```
     watch_process.php?username='". $_POST['Username']."'
```

Why not just do like so:

```
      // REMEMBER TO urlencode() THE $_POST['username'] VARIABLE
      $url = "watch_process.php?username=". urlencode($_POST['Username']);

     // AND THEN GET BACK YOUR QUERY STRING NORMALLY WITHOUT ANY TRIMMING LIKE SO:
     <?php echo $_GET['username']; ?>

     // AND IF YOU NEED SINGLE QUOTES AROUND THE $_GET['username'] VARIABLE 
     // YOU CAN EASILY ADD IT ONCE YOU'VE RETRIEVED IT LIKE SO:
     $username   = "'" . $_GET['username'] . "'";
```

But it is assumable that ***You most likely don't need the single-quotes*** except if you really otherwise do....

Comment: Also  add a note that OP should really, ***really*** use `urlencode` as well on the post variable

Comment: @Martin        Thanks for that. I also saw that someone ( Frayne Konok) already mentioned it first though... but all the same thanks for bringing that up here again ;-)

Comment: I was saying so that you can add this suggestion in to your answer ;-)